# Regex Preg_match Pattern for Numbers In Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, regex, sorting

I have an array of numbers that I need to search through a multidimensional array for.

I have a thousand records of songs. Each song has an array of float values that I need to search through, and I'll need to retrieve the songs if the first digits of each float value match any float number in my array.

So for example my array of numbers I need to find are:

```
array(14, 18.12, 12.1290, 55.01)
```

and the songs are sorted in a json file like so:

```
{"id": 129112, "name": "XYZ Song", "values": { 14.1290, 55.0192, 129 } }
```

Currently my for loops are taking too long to loop through all the records.

I think I need to sort through the values with a preg_match function and the right pattern (except I'm terrible with regex), what do you guys think?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more sample data and explain whether each value should or shouldn't match? It would probably also be helpful to understand what the values in the `values` array are (length, volume, ???) to come up with a matching strategy.

Comment: no, it sounds like you need to (a) parse that JSON into normal data, and then probably (b) stick it in a database so _it_ can do the searching for you, in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code. This code may help you

```
<?php 
    // PHP program to carry out multidimensional array search

    // Function to recursively search for a given value 
    function multi_array_search($search_value, $array, $id_path) {

        if(is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) { 
      
            foreach($array as $key => $value) { 

                $temp_path = $id_path;
          
                // Adding current key to search path
                $temp_path[] = $value;

                // Check if this value is an array 
                // with atleast one element 
                if(is_array($value) && count($value) > 0) { 
                    $res_path = multi_array_search( 
                            $search_value, $value, $temp_path); 
                } 
                else if($value == $search_value) {
                    print_r($temp_path);
                } 
            } 
        }
    } 

    // Multidimensional (Three dimensional) array   as suggested by you
    $songs_array= array( 
        0 => array( 
            "id" => "129112", 
            "name" => "X Song", 
            "value" => array( 14.1290, 329, 129 ) 
        ), 
  
        1 => array( 
            "id" => "129113", 
            "name" => "XY Song", 
            "value" => array( 14.1291, 55.0192, 229 ) 
        ), 
  
        2 => array( 
            "ic" => "129114", 
            "name" => "XYZ Song", 
            "value" => array( 14.1292, 55.0193, 388 ) 
        ) 
    ); 

    $songs= multi_array_search('329', $songs_array, array());

?>
```

Here I have searched for `329` in `$song_array` and
Result is :
[image]